# Formatting idea for 2 rows table

Tags: tables, formatting, tabulary

Hey im looking for a solution to format this table in a good looking way. I like the booktabs formatting for tables that read vertically but i want this one to be read horizontally. This is what i came up with but i found it not looking solid and sharp enough. Do you have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it is a two steps process, it visually makes more sense to go with a horizontal line between the spaces as for the redundant text you can use it as header of a third row (before step1). Furthermore the same text is present for your concentration `c`, time `t` and temperature `T`. For clarity I'd use an explanation in the caption of the table for the redundant details and in parentheses the units. In addition, maybe changing from `t` to `i` as a notation for time points. This would look like this:

```
Steps \ Variables  |    c(mM)     i(min)    T(°C)
-------------------------------------------------
1                  |     1         2880      25
-------------------------------------------------
2                  |     1           30      70
```

caption including an explanation of `immic1m2`. Which experiment, condition, etc?
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the Idea thats good! My concern is that the concentration is given for one species, but it could be for e.g step 3 that the concentration is a mixture of lets say c12/c8 at ratios 5:1... may i ask you for another idea how to implement that? i dont want to bloat the infos, just clear and sharp. B

Comment: glad to help! Regarding the ratios to explicit some concentrations i assume you are referring to steps 12 and 8 when you write `c12`and `c8`, respectively. so how about just using that as a fraction followed by the ratio in brackets [5:1]? :-)

Comment: you have to define at some point `c_s` with `s` steps if you use the notation `\frac{c_{12}}{c_{8}}`